# Reduce number of points in polygon

Tags: .net, sql-server, polygon

I have a table in sqlserver with 55k geometry points. Each point are 5 meters apart and have a value assigned to them. My task is to draw these points in a google map.
Early I concluded that google maps could not handle drawing the 55k points. So I figured I had to group the points by value (10% intervals, 1-9,10-19 etc) to form polygons. However the polygons still consist of the same amount of points. I need to reduce the number of points in each polygon.
I need the polygons to atleast roughly keep their shape, so convex hull is out of the question.

Getting the concave hull/alpha shape would be the best solution I guess, but I haven't been able to find an implementation of it for sqlserver 2008 r2 or a .NET assembly / function.

It would also be acceptablef or me to just get the points that creates the outer line of the polygon, so I can pass those points to Google Maps and make it draw the polygons.

Here is a picture of how the collection of points for a polygon looks:

[image]

Comment: Do you just need to see the positions of the points? Or are you going to use the polygons for some other purpose like to test if a point is inside, or to fill the polygons? What I am asking is if it is ok to treat the polygons purely as a set of points or not?

Comment: I need to draw the polygons in a Google map, so I do not care for the points inside the polygon. My experience is that Google Maps will draw lines to each point inside if I pass it a collection of all the points. So I just need to points that make the outer border of the polygon. Here is an image of how it should look in the end. This image is created using a GIS program that can handle drawing all the points. [Image](http://imgur.com/UINA1fv)

Comment: You didn't answer my question... is it ok to just draw 55,000 points on the map and ignore the fact that they form a polygon?

Comment: In theory it would yes, but the map cannot handle drawing 55k points, hence why I am forced to create polygons to reduced the number of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Each point are 5 meters apart and have a value assigned to them."

That sounds a lot like you can treat the point set as a sparse 2D (boolean) matrix. You can use this to remove redundant points in the center of the shape. This could be applied to alpha shapes as well, but it only works well when the points are tightly packed together as in the case in your example and as implied by the above line in your question.

The pseudocode (not sure how to actually implement it in the languages you seek) for a single pass looks like this:

```
Verify that the points are lexicographically sorted
Create a list to hold the unfiltered points
Create a set of the points for the fast membership tested needed
For each point:
    If none of patterns are present:
        Add the point to the list of unfiltered points
return list of unfiltered points
```

The patterns are based on a 3x3 matrix, which represents the offsets from the center. So the center is (00,00), since it is not offset from the points. There are 12 main patterns to look for in the 3x3. Which can then be generalized into larger odd sized square matrices (5x5, 7x7, 9x9, 13x13...). The 3x3 with the offsets looks like this:

```
[[(-5,+5),(00,+5),(+5,+5)],
 [(-5,00),(00,00),(+5,00)],
 [(-5,-5),(00,-5),(+5,-5)]]
```

The 5x5 with offsets looks like this:

```
[[(-10,+10),(-05,+10),(00,+10),(+05,+10),(+10,+10)],
 [(-10,+05),(-05,+05),(00,+05),(+05,+05),(+10,+05)],
 [(-10,000),(-05,000),(00,000),(+05,000),(+10,000)],
 [(-10,-05),(-05,-05),(00,-05),(+05,-05),(+10,-05)],
 [(-10,-10),(-05,-10),(00,-10),(+05,-10),(+10,-10)]]
```

Just using one of the 12 patterns below will remove a lot of points leaving just the outer and inner (if the polygon isn't filled in) hull. The additional patterns are used to reduce the number of points in the outer/inner hull. This may be enough for your purposes. However, each additional pass should only remove about half the remaining points, but the number of patterns to look for grows at a rate of O(p^2). Note that p is O(d) where d is the greatest distance between two points in the point set, which in this special case is O(N). This should be enough to allow for a simple graph algorithm to extract the outer concave hull by picking an element on the convex hull and walking around the shape to produce the concave hull. Further passes will further reduce the number of points until some point dependent on which patterns are used. In the extreme case, it'll reduce it to a triangle.

There are then 12 patterns to look for to determine if the center point is redundant. This is done by checking if the center point is on a line (for the first four) or an approximate line/arc (last 8). Note that only one of these are needed to actually hollow out the point set. The rest are simply used to further reduce the number of points.

```
 1. [[0,1,0], |  2. [[0,0,0], |  3. [[1,0,0], |  4. [[0,0,1],
     [0,1,0], |      [1,1,1], |      [0,1,0], |      [0,1,0],  
     [0,1,0]] |      [0,0,0]] |      [0,0,1]] |      [1,0,0]]

 5. [[1,0,0], |  6. [[0,0,1], | 7.  [[0,0,1], | 8. [[0,0,0],
     [0,1,0], |      [0,1,0], |      [1,1,0], |     [1,1,0],  
     [0,1,0]] |      [0,1,0]] |      [0,0,0]] |     [0,0,1]]  

 9. [[0,1,0], | 10. [[0,1,0], | 11. [[1,0,0], | 12. [[0,0,0],
     [0,1,0], |      [0,1,0], |      [0,1,1], |      [0,1,1],  
     [0,1,0]] |      [0,1,0]] |      [0,0,0]] |      [1,0,0]]
```

The patterns are intended to form arcs with the center point as the point under consideration. The above arcs are really more for example. To make things easier, only two more general patterns are used they are listed below. Note that at least one 2 must be present at at least one 3 must be present. If this is done until

```
13. [[2,2,2], | 14. [[2,0,3],
     [0,1,0], |      [2,1,3],
     [3,3,3]] |      [2,0,3]]
```

Extending 13 and 14 to a 5x5 (second pass) results in the following:

```
15. [[2,2,2,2,2], | 16. [[2,0,0,0,3],
     [0,0,0,0,0], |      [2,0,0,0,3],
     [0,0,1,0,0], |      [2,0,1,0,3],
     [0,0,0,0,0], |      [2,0,0,0,3],
     [3,3,3,3,3]] |      [2,0,0,0,3]]
```

A further generalization of 13 and 14 resolves some offset issues and leads the following in the 5x5 case. Although, care needs to be taken to avoid duplicating work of previous passes.

```
15. [[2,2,2,2,2], | 16. [[2,2,0,3,3],
     [2,2,2,2,2], |      [2,2,0,3,3],
     [0,0,1,0,0], |      [2,2,1,3,3],
     [3,3,3,3,3], |      [2,2,0,3,3],
     [3,3,3,3,3]] |      [2,2,0,3,3]]
```

Leaving the outer/inner hull intact:

The goal of the above is was to reduce the number of points and I included points in the hulls in that as well. If it is desired to only remove points between the hulls, then each pattern can check for more than two neighboring points only removing the point if they don't exist. The most extreme example would be the following 3x3 pattern, where the center point is only redundant if it's completely surrounded. Using a 5x5 pattern first instead of 3x3 would make the outer/inner hull as 3 points thick and has no effect being applied after any 3x3 pattern:

```
17. [[1,1,1],
     [1,1,1],
     [1,1,1]]
```

Comment: Over the weekend (I've been away on a trip with the family), I have come to a similar solution. At least I think so..
My thought was this:

1)Get the points for each X value in the list of points for the polygon.
2)Find min and max value for Y, as the rest of the points wont be part of the border.
3)Check that Ymax - Ymin / (number of points-1) == 5. Might be a little off here, but this is to make sure that there are no "holes" in the list of values. 
4)If there is a missing value, then split the values around the missing value and do step2 over again with each new list created.

Comment: Damn, I need to get better at formatting the text correct :(

I'll give you points for the correct solution. If my self-found solution does not work, I'll take a closer look at yours.

Comment: Although, it depends on what step 4 actually looks like, but I'm fairly sure your splitting will result in the same answer as a single pass with pattern #2, which is good enough to get you an outer and inner hull. The need to handle where to split makes your approach have a more overhead requiring either multiple passes though the data or sorting each list of X value points when there is a need to split. Mine does have multiple passes, but I included those to further reduce the size of the resulting polygon (if needed).

Comment: @Kennedine: FYI, I made a few edits to my post. Clarified that a single pattern (checking just two points per point in the point set) can reduce it just an the inner and outer hull. Also added a section at the end about how to avoid removing points from the inner/outer hull while removing the inner points.

Comment: Step 4 is not needed for this shape no. The "bottom" layer, the polygon from the lowest value interval will need it though. For that polygon the outer boundary will have several values for the same x. Put very simple just like an 'S' would, the shape is not the shape of an 'S', but I hope you get the picture :)

Comment: Perhaps you should include in your answer what shape you are expecting? There are a few cases I can see where horizontal splitting would be used in the given example. Specifically, the four protrusions in the bottom left, and the rounded bulge near the bottom. Not sure what you mean by lowest value interval though. Might be something to expand upon in your question. You also might want to include what you are/were hoping to see in the question (for future reference).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see 55,000 points on a map but don't care that they form a polygon - so you will not be able to fill the polygon with colour, for example, you could use Google Fusion Tables.

They support 100,000 points per layer and 5 layers in toto - i.e. up to 500,000 points. They are lightning fast too as you access them via an SQL-type language that runs on Google's servers - exactly where your data will be when you upload it.

You load your CSV into a Fusion Table in your Google drive and get a key to that table and you then use the key in your Javascript.

I created the following website with Fusion Tables and I am a zero in Javascript! See Skyscan website [here](http://skyscan.co.uk/mapsearch)

[image]

Comment: I do not think my customer would accept that the data is stored on googles servers permanent. I also do not really want to have to include a google drive into the mix. I want a solution that requires no manual labor as there will coming new datasets in on a regular basis.

Comment: I understand. By the way, you can automate the uploading of new datasets. You could also generate the points, screen-grab the output and then delete the dataset from your Google Drive. But, I am sure someone else on StackOverflow will write that Convex Hull algorithm for you ;-)

Comment: I cannot use a convex hull, as I need to keep the shape of my polygons. For the inner ones a convex hull is ok, but for the larger ones with a more irregular shape it is not an option.

The perfect solution would be a concave hull/ alpha shape. I will however be more than happy with "just" getting the outer shape of each polygon. Thanks for your effords, it is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried implementing any simple-ish algorithms and checked the results? Maybe you could find the largest and smallest Northing and Easting to get the enclosing box of all your points, then divide that into (say) 100 rectangles (i.e. 10x10) and randomly (say) remove (say) 30% of the points from (say) the N rectangles that contain the most points...

Comment: No I have not, it might work for some of the polygons(the large ones), but for the smaller ones I am quite sure it wont get my anywhere.

I cannot help but feel that sql server should be able to build a polygon from the points and give me the exterior ring. However I am stuck for now with an geometry collection of points.